# Node.js/Express.js API rate limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rate-limiting

**Context**:
The API that I need to rate-limit is `request OTP`. A user needs to request it to be able to log in. He can use his phone or email.

By that stage, I don't have the user id or JWT token yet.
That's why I first decided to limit the API by a user's IP address.

An example of set up:

```
  windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 5,
  message: "Too many requests, please try again later in 10 minutes",
  keyGenerator: (request, response) => {
    return requestIp.getClientIp(request);
  },
});
```

However, what I don't like in this approach is that a user can change the IP by proxy or so and avoid the limitation.
I could set the limiting by for example phone/email that a user sends in the request and the IP, but email/phone also could be easily changed.

**My questions**:

1. What you can advise in the case that I described above? I mean, maybe there is a way to limit a user before we have his userId or token
2. What is better practice in the rate-limiting? I mean, maybe instead of limiting users separately the better option is to make a limit on the app itself, or another way

Comment: Can you really change your phone or email faster than 5 times in 10 minutes (if that's the rate you want to allow)?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking what if someone will decide to "play" with the API and request it directly, let's say in postman or terminal.

So, he could easily write a basic function that will generate random emails and make the request

Comment: Don't you verify the email or phone number (by sending out a confirmation code)?

Comment: Yes, I am verifying it to make sure that the account with the proper email/phone exists.

Alright, I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, do you have any recommendations about the rate-limiting itself? Any best practices, etc.

I mean, as far as I can see from different articles, the common approach is to use IP for that. However, because of the reasons that I described above, that seems not ideal for me

Comment: Sorry, am no expert on that.

Comment: @slhn.dev You could join a discussion about limiting not authorised users in [this `rate-limiter-flexible` issue on Github](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/issues/119)